# Rails, dynamic emails sent do different email address on staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So for static email in the system, I have a staging environment config setup which works well.

With dynamic emails, I have this code in my mailer.rb file.

```
if RAILS_ENV == 'staging'
    recipients STAGING_TEST_EMAIL     
else
    recipients request[:email]
end
```

This works, I just wanted to know if there was a tidier or better way to do this or if this is OK in terms of best practice.

Comment: You could use `Rails.env.staging?` instead of the `==` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

One option, is to modify the staging servers mailing gem..

IE...

```
def email.press_send
  recipients STAGING_TEST_EMAIL
end
```

My personal favorite...

is to talk to the sys admin and arrange for email sent from the staging, test, box directly into a file, so then you can view it.

ie, all email sent out is sent to this user "test_email", who has this .forward "| cat >> /tmp/new_mail.txt"

Comment: Hey not sure I understand sorry what "email.press_send" means?